# how to connect remote mysqlserver and insert from local server db

Tags: mysql

i am trying to insert/replace statement to add on remote mysql server from local db configured with data.i am using below statement. but its selecting source and destination from remote server, i want to define local server as source which got db pswx_raccar.
mysql -h 161.x.x.x -u repair -p5ThNqHdyRwC -D repair_raccar -e "REPLACE INTO repair_raccar.positions_1906 SELECT * FROM pswx_raccar.positions_1906 WHERE device_time BETWEEN '2023-06-11 00:00:00' AND '2023-07-01 23:59:00'";
plz help

tried to copy from repair DB to production DB to replace missing data between timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the command line tool with the -h param

```
mysql -h 161.x.x.x -u repair -p5ThNqHdyRwC -D repair_raccar -e "INSERT INTO pswx_raccar.positions_1906 SELECT * FROM repair_raccar.positions_1906 WHERE device_time BETWEEN '2023-06-11 00:00:00' AND '2023-07-01 23:59:00'"
```

Comment: i am using same command but its not fetching from localhost